# How to compare a dictionary's values(lists) against a separate list?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, iteration

Lets say I'm given a dictionary:

```
students = {"adrian":["a","b","c","d"], "jamie":["b","b","a","d"], "adam":["a","c","d","d"]}
```

And the list:

```
answers=["a","b","c","d"]
```

I simply want to check each element matches from answers at its given index against the values in the dictionary. In short compare each list against answers.
i would then print the amount of times a student was correct.

For example if i compared the value of the key "adrian" against the answers i would get 4. And if i compared jamie against answers I would get 2. And if i compared adam to answers i would get 2.

How can i compare the two?

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: Kindly edit the question and add the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> students = {"adrian":["a","b","c","d"], "jamie":["b","b","a","d"], "adam":["a","c","d","d"]}
>>> answers = ["a","b","c","d"]
>>> {s:sum(t == a for t, a in zip(students[s], answers)) for s in students}
{'jamie': 2, 'adam': 2, 'adrian': 4}
```

This for each students `zip`s their answers with the answers and then compares them then it sums up the resulting Booleans.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
students = {"adrian":["a","b","c","d"], "jamie":["b","b","a","d"], "adam":["a","c","d","d"]}
answers=["a","b","c","d"]
df = pd.DataFrame(students)
df.apply(lambda x: x==answers).sum()
```

A bit explaination:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x==answers)
```

will compare answers for each student, resulting the following array:

```
    adam adrian  jamie
0   True   True  False
1  False   True   True
2  False   True  False
3   True   True   True
```

.sum() will do a column-wise sum(cast True to 1 and False to 0), reducing the array to:

```
adam      2
adrian    4
jamie     2
```

Comment: Even if this approach is a working one I would not say its pretty good to use pandas when is not in the question tag. At least add an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
def get_correct_answers_count(given_answers,
                              correct_answers):
    return sum(1
               for student_answer, correct_answer in zip(given_answers,
                                                         correct_answers)
               if student_answer == correct_answer)


students_correct_answers_count = {
    student_name: get_correct_answers_count(given_answers=student_answers,
                                            correct_answers=answers)
    for student_name, student_answers in students.items()}
```

gives us

> {'adrian': 4, 'jamie': 2, 'adam': 2}

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip() to get a combination of values and answers

```
for k,v in students.items():
    ans = 0
    for i, j in zip(v,answers):
        if i==j:
            ans+=1
    print ans
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this works

```
students = {"adrian":["a","b","c","d"],
          "jamie":["b","b","a","d"],
          "adam":["a","c","d","d"]}
answers = ["a","b","c","d"]

results = {}

for k,v in students.items():
    results [k] = 0
    for i,answer in enumerate(v):
        if answers[i] == v[i]:
            results[k]+=1

print (results)
```

{'adrian': 4, 'adam': 2, 'jamie': 2}

Comment: it depends on what your definition of complex is.

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on *set()*

Example

```
data = {'jamie': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
answers = ['b', 'd', 'c', 'd']
tuples = map(set, zip(data['jamie'], answers))
reduce(lambda y, coll: (len(coll) - 1) + y , tuples, 0)

Out[8]: 2
```

The example is using the fact that the datatype set can only contain unique. So by zipping the two lists jamie and answers I get tuples. If the tuple contains two of the same the `set()` will make it unique.

When I reduce the list of tuples I use the fact that if there is more then one element in the set, it is a sign of a wrong answer & count it.